# ¿Como debo hacer para leer dos números y luego calcular su producto por sumas sucesivas?

Tags: python, loops

¿Cómo debería hacer para leer dos números y luego calcular su producto según sumas sucesivas como en este ejemplo: 4*3 o 4+4+4?

```
A=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
B=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
C=0
while A>B:
    print("El producto segun la suma seria" ,(a))
    C=C+1
```

¿Podría hacerlo así? Y si es así, ¿cómo debería declararle a "A" las veces que se tiene que sumar?

Comment: Ivan te recomiendo repasarte el concepto de un ciclo `while` y su variable de control. Llevas varias preguntas cometiendo el mismo error. En este ejemplo `mientra A>B: haz..`. pero ¿donde modificas `A` o `B`  dentro del ciclo? Si `A` es mayor que `B` tienes un ciclo infinito, en caso contrario el `while` nunca inicia. Si no entiendes este concepto aunque te demos la solución no vas a aprender nada y seguirás cometiendolo. La lógica de tu problema es muy sencilla: Mientras `B` no sea cero: `C = C + A` y restamos uno a `B`. Al terminar el ciclo imprimes el resultado (`C`).

Comment: Recuerda que antes de hacer un ciclo While debes tener claro cuando entra y cuando sale o termina, si pretendes decir que mientras A>B opere, entonces debes en algún lado del ciclo restarle a alguna variable que puede ser A, o en caso contrario dejaras un bucle como dice FJsevilla. Recomiendo que leas mas de el ciclo while antes de preguntar para que estés mejor orientado.

Answer (score 0):

PARA SUMAR X VECES EL MISMO NUMERO PODRIA MODIFICAR SU CODIGO A ALGO COMO ESTO:

A = int(input("Ingrese un numero:")) /**siendo el numero a sumar "B" veces**/

B = int(input("Ingrese un numero:")) /**las veces a sumar el numero anterior**/
C = 0
while B>0:

```
print("El producto segun la suma seria" ,(a))
C+=A
B-=1
```

AUNQUE CONSIDERO QUE DEBE SACAR EL PRINT DE SU CICLO Y MOSTRAR SOLO RESULTADO FINAL A SU USUARIO.

Comment: ¿Seguro que es `A+=A`...? Recuerda formatear el código seleccionándolo y pulsando el botón `{}` del editor o pulsando `Ctrl` + `k`,

Comment: FJSevilla, lo siento, deje pasar detalle. Ya he corregido, mi respuesta es correcta ahora. Gracias por replica.

Comment: Por curiosidad, para que serviria el igual ahi?Y por que no es lo mismo poner la suma en vez de la suma con el igual?Es una duda inquietante